# Awful performance of AMD Athlon II X4 640

Tags: windows-7, drivers, cpu, amd-athlon

I have bought the above processor along with 12 gigabytes of RAM and an AMD R9 270X graphics card.

Now my FPS in several games (a.e. League of Legends or World of Warcraft WotLK) are really bad and it seems to be CPU limited.

In WoW, I got 20 FPS on lowest (!) settings and 15 in hightest (Ultra + VSR 1440p). GPU-Z shows up to 60% GPU load, so no problem here.

My OS is Windows 7. I tried 10, but I could not find a coprocessor driver for it.

What I already tried:

- Looking at temperatures: I had problems with running into the temperature limit, because I limited the fan RPM. Fan is now running on higher speed, I also have another cooler that I will put it on when the performance gets better. Temp are now at 55°C max (70 before which is the max for this CPU).
- Disabled thermal throttling in BIOS
- Installed the newest coprocessor driver (included in the nvidia chipset driver of my mainboard. Will post the mainboard name later, but its an asrock with an nvidia chipset)
- Changed the OS (Windows 7 -> Windows 10, but no coprocessor driver available)

Comment: If you think it is CPU limited then you might want to monitor CPU usage during the game (e..g run the game on one display and run resmon.exe on a second screen. Also look at how many cores are active.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. One core seems to be near the 100%, the others not. But I get 60+ FPS with a Core2Quad Q6600 which should be a bit slower, so I'm really confused u.u

Comment: If the game is old or badly written it will be single treaded. That means it will only use one core. Performance then depends a lot on that core and it could be that either the core2 architecture is faster, or maybe it just happens to sync better with this one game. (as in, the timings happen to lucily coincide).

Comment: Okay, I will benchmark and try more games and write back again. Do you have another idea where the bad performance could come from?